# How to clear a bunch of python labels but only when they are called

Tags: python, tkinter, label

Hello fellow stackoverflowers,

I'm writing a small program that does some database stuff and I am trying to delete a label but only when it is called.

Here is one of my full functions but the part at the **bottom** is where I am trying to delete the labels.

```
def entry_a_result(self):



      count = 0
      counta = 0
      fullfile = fullGUI.f_or()
      if len(self.e.get()) > 0:
          #print(self.e.get())
        file_obj = open(fullfile, "r+")
        fullstring = self.e.get()
        x = fullstring[5:9]
        try:
          while(fullstring.startswith("get *") and count < 1):
             self.la = Label(root, text = file_obj.read() + "\n" + "--------")
             self.la.pack(side=TOP, anchor=N)
             count = 1
          while(fullstring.startswith("get |" + x) and count < 1):
            count = 1
            lines = file_obj.readlines()

            for line in lines:
                  if x in line:
                    self.lb = Label(root, text=line + "\n" + "--------")
                    self.lb.pack(side=TOP, anchor=N)
                  else:
                    pass

          **while(fullstring.startswith("clear") and count < 1):

               count = 1
               labela = self.la.winfo_exists()
               labelb = self.lb.winfo_exists()
               if labela == 1:
                 self.la.destroy()
               if labelb == 1:
                 self.lb.destroy()**
```

What seems to be happening is that winfo_exists() is only working when the label is created and won't attach itself to the variable otherwise.

To clear up any confusion,

I'm trying to destroy or remove a label when and only when the label is existing in this case whenever I call a certain parameter within the program, which is currently working(in that my params work)

Comment: I don't know why you use `count` and `while count<1` if you could use only `if/elif/elif` (without `count`)

Comment: you could use `self.la = None` to inform that widget not exists yet. And then you can use `if self.la:` to check it - and you don't need `winfo_exists()`

Comment: `self.la` and `self.lb` keeps only last label - maybe keep all labels on some list. `self.la = []` and `self.la.append( Label(...) )`

Comment: `else: pass` is useless - you can remove it.

Comment: self.la and self.lb are labels themselves and I tried using self.la = None but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: set `self.la = None` before you assign any `Label` this way you can see if you assign any `Label`. But I thing you should rather use list `self.la = []` to keep all labels which you create - now you keep only last label.

Comment: I did that but it can't seem to find any items in my list..

Comment: maybe you put `self.la = []` in wrong place and you remove all elements. It should be in `__init__`

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are using self.la? Because that is my label name could I do self.labellist =[] and then append from there?

Comment: I got it to work :) Thanks!